# Master page with JQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, master-pages

I'm new to JQM and at the moment I'm exploring it.

I want to create a master page, but I'm not quite sure how should I do it using JQM.

This is what I've tried - the code is from my master page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="headerID">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>
                Language</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <select id="ddlLanguage" runat="server" data-theme="e" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">English </option>
                <option value="2">Bulgarian </option>
                <option value="3">Spanish </option>
                <option value="4">Norwegian </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="contentID">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpmain" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was imagining that the actual master page html should be inside one `<div data-role="content">` and the

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpmain" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

inside another `<div data-role="content">` However I this version when I run my project I can see only the user interface from my pages, but not the one from the master page. I tried to move these HTML around and I obtain a stituation where the master's page interface was visiable, but not the pages' interface. Saddly I cannot pick out how to do this.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I've done. In the master page in the `data-role="header"` part I inserted the actual master's page interface - say drop down list. Than in the `data-role="content"` I inserted the ContentPlaceHolder and now I have the expected behavior -> drop down list as a header of every page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="contentID">
        <div data-role="header">
            <select id="ddlLanguage" runat="server" data-theme="e" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">English </option>
                <option value="2">Bulgarian </option>
                <option value="3">Spanish </option>
                <option value="4">Norwegian </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpmain" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
</div>
```